# Array equality checking algorithm not working in certain cases

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a piece of code which checks for equality of arrays. It works like a charm when using it like:

```
[1, 2, 3].equals([1, 2, 3]); // true
[1, 2, 3].equals([1, 2, 4]); // false
```

The above result is obvious and correct, of course. However, the following case fails:

```
[1, 2, undefined].equals([1, 2, undefined]);
// Error:  Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined
```

What could be the cause of it? I check whether it has the property before using it (`if (this[i].equals)`), so why does it say this? It is also true that `undefined === undefined`, so I do not see what's the problem.

The function:

```
Array.prototype.equals = function(arr) {
    if (this.length !== arr.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].equals) {
            if (!this[i].equals(arr[i])) {
                return false;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (this[i] !== arr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @patrickdw beat me to the correct answer, so I'll just add this: a) I suggest that you add `if (this==arr) return true;` to the top of your test for a fast out when the same object is passed as an argument; b) you should cache the length of your array for speed, `for (var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;++i){ .. }`

Comment: @Phrogz: I'm not suffering from benchmark problems, but time savings are never bad, thanks. Also thanks for your first suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
    if (this[i].equals) {
```

should be:

```
    if (this[i] && this[i].equals) {
```

so that if `this[i]` is `undefined`, you won't be trying to access a property on `undefined`.

---

**EDIT:** Since you seem to be testing for an Array, it will be safer to do a more explicit test, since any Object could potentially have an `.equals` property.

You may want to do this instead:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( this[i] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
```

It's a bit longer, but will accurately detect an Array, even if it was created using the `new` keyword, which would throw off the `typeof` operator.

Comment: Yes this is the solution, thanks. Is it unallowed to even check for properties of `undefined`?

Comment: @pimvdb: That is correct. You'll get a `TypeError` when trying to access a property on `undefined`.

Comment: @pimvdb: By the way, since the point of that `if()` statement is to only enter if you have an Array, you may want to do a more explicit test. If the item at `this[i]` happens to be an Object that has an `equals` property, the test will succeed. I'll update.

Comment: I can be rather sure that the `Object` doesn't have an `equals` function as I know what libraries I'm using. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @pimvdb: Whatever you prefer, but `equals` wouldn't need to be prototyped into `Object`. If `Number` had an `equals` property, you'd have the same issue. Or if someone created an object literal or some other instance that has its own `equals` property. Anyway, just thought I'd mention it. :o)

Comment: On second thought you are right - some extra checking is not too bad at all. Thanks!